# AuthGuard wait for API call

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, angular11

I'm trying to block access to the admin dashboard itself for non-admin users. For this, I have to check in the back-end if the token is valid and if so, that the user is actually an administrator. I seem to be able to block it but I can't figure out how to wait for the API call in the AuthGuard in Angular 11? Do I have to make the canActivate() method async or something?

AuthenticationService:

```
  // This method works and returns an Observable<boolean>
  public hasUserRole(theAccessToken: string, userRole: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        accessToken: theAccessToken,
        requiredUserRole: userRole,
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<any>(Constants.API_ENDPOINT_GET_USER_ROLES, httpOptions);
  }

  // This method, I don't know how to implement... I tried .pipe and .tap and whatnot but I can't get anything to wait for the API call to finish.
  public isLoggedInAndHasUserRole(token: string, userRole: string): boolean {
      // return this.hasUserRole(token, userRole); // TODO: How to wait for this API call? .map doesn't seem to work in Angular11 and I can't get the .pipe() to work either.
  }
```

Auth Guard (works but I don't know how to wait for the API call):

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const token = this.commonService.getToken();

    if (token !== '' && token !== undefined) {

      if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedInAndHasUserRole(token, 'Admin')) {
<snip for brevity>
```

Image with the API result
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[canActivate has several return values.](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) You can return `Observable<boolean>` and the auth guard will only continue after that observable has been resolved.

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    const token = this.commonService.getToken();

    if (token !== '' && token !== undefined) {
        return this.authenticationService.isLoggedInAndHasUserRole(token, 'Admin').pipe(
        map((hasRole) => {
            if (hasRole) {
                return true;
            } else {
                this.commonService.navigateToHome();
                return false; //
            }
        }));
    } else {
       this.commonService.navigateToLogin();
       return false;
    }
}
```

In your authorization service:

```
 public isLoggedInAndHasUserRole(token: string, userRole: string): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.hasUserRole(token, userRole);
  }
```

Comment: How would I implement the isLoggedInAndHasUserRole() in such case? If I use a .subscribe(), it would always return false and the AuthGuard is not waiting.

Comment: No need to subscribe anything. If you API endpoint returns a boolean, then your current code should work

Comment: isLoggedInAndHasUserRole() is empty and doesn't even compile, therefore it cannot possibly work... What am I missing? Or did you mean the other method (which my AuthGuard doesn't wait for)? Can you please also include the service code in your answer please?

Comment: What is the return value of API_ENDPOINT_GET_USER_ROLES? An array of roles?
If yes, then isLoggedInAndHasUserRole should return the following:
`return this.hasUserRole(token, userRole).pipe(map((userRoles) => {
    return userRoles.find(r => r === userRole)
}));`

Comment: That's a constant string with the value of: https://localhost:<snip>/api/token/hasUserRole

Comment: Sorry, I meant the API return value. What do you get when you call this API?

Comment: I added an image to the OP with the API result with placeholder code, which shows: data = true
If I use your 'pipe-comment' I get an error that it can't convert Observable<boolean> to boolean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228087/discussion-between-sombrerogalaxy-and-napoleon).